# How to Drop Added Column After Using "df.sample(frac=1)"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a .csv file that I import into a Python Pandas dataframe. It starts off looking like this:

[image: First]

...then after I run some one-hot encoding, I employ a "df.sample(frac=1)" function to randomize all the rows of the dataframe, which gets me a result that looks like this:

[image: Second]

...but how do I now get rid of that added first row? I don't want that row to be included in my next regression step. I've tried:

```
df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

...but all that does is order that first column into ascending order (1 - X).

Note how the column doesn't have a name, so using ".drop" with a column name won't work? Ideas? Thanks!!!

Comment: `df.to_csv('file_name.csv', index=False)`

Comment: Ugh, of course. So that index column isn't actually a part of the dataframe, it's just used for indexing? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first row corresponds to the index for each and every row so you can simply fix that with using `index=False`

so when you are writing to a CSV file make sure you add this parameter and generate the CSV to remove the index and dump the data frame to the CSV file

`Df.to_csv("finalCSV.csv",index=False)`

Refer to the documentation here

[pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)